# Websockets can't connect to server

Tags: php, websocket

I am trying to obtain some education on websockets but I can't really find a decent tutorial. All tutorials out there instruct you to download a server and teach you how to use it. I'm more interested in how the server actually works and how I can control it on a remote host, like a hosting provider.

Anyway if I wanna learn there really aren't many options other than to download a built server and start inspecting. So I downloaded the server given in this tutorial http://dev.tutsplus.com/tutorials/start-using-html5-websockets-today--net-13270

The problem for now is that I can't even seem to connect to it. I'm running XAMPP on Win7, so it's completely relevant to the tutorial and appears quite easy, however I fail. I've managed to start the server, but when I open `client.php` I get

> Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at
>   ws://localhost:8000/pol/newWS/server/startDaemon.php.      var socket =
>   new WebSocket(host);

Fortunately chrome appears to provide a more detailed error message

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/pol/newWS/server/startDaemon.php' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header is missing

Javascript's host variable is set to 'ws://localhost:8000/pol/newWS/server/startDaemon.php', that's where the server is located on my localhost. I haven't made any changes to the server. Can anyone help me get this thing going? Thanks in advance!

Comment: WebSockets in PHP is a bit of a hassle.  I suggest considering Node.js for this.  The JavaScript implementations of WebSockets server-side are more robust and easier to use.

Comment: @Brad thanks for the suggestion but I really would like to avoid using node.js after I've seen this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1e1zzna-dNw

Comment: Ha, that video is hilarious.  Thanks for the laugh.  The guy that made that video clearly misses the point, and has no idea what he's talking about.  No clue at all.

Comment: You can look into a Ruby websocket server. Reading the Ruby code is relatively easy... Search for Faye or GRHttp. [GRHttp] is an independent server, so you can pull insights from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found some WS server I have downloaded in the past which works pretty well. I can't confirm for any security issues but if anyone knows or finds anything please don't spare us the sharing. I searched for some info in the comments but I couldn't find anything about the creator so I can't really give any credits.

[files here](http://www.4shared.com/rar/7RIos1tuce/PHPWebSocket-Chat-master.html)

Answer (score 0):

Websockets in PHP are generally a pain in the ass. Even if you use a library like [rachet](http://socketo.me/) you need to start it separately, not through a webserver.

As brad said, consider using node.js or the excellent [autobahn.ws for python](http://autobahn.ws/python/).

Comment: Well I'd just like to get this daemon server connection to go right for now

Comment: The tutorial you linked only seems to cover the client side. You also need to have a websocket server to connect to.

Comment: Yeah it's in the source files, but some header is not sent. I am reading php manual but I can't figure how to send it correctly